# Request.Url fails unless prepended by a String

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms, master-pages

I am trying to put a canonical link into each page in the header automatically. The pages in question are WebForms which have a Master Page.

In the `<head>` of the Master Page I have the following:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<% Response.Write(Request.Url.ToString) %>" />
```

But this displays:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="MasterPages/%3C%25%20Response.Write(Request.Url.ToString)%20%25%3E" />
```

However if I prepend a blank string like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<% Response.Write("" & Request.Url.ToString) %>" />
```

It works:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:60898/default.aspx" />
```

Strangely when I take out the blank string the syntax colouring changes from black to blue when I compile so it looks like a compiler bug to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Use ToString as a function : `Request.Url.ToString()`. 
Worked for me.

Comment: Did it show the same error I posted for you without the parenthesis? `.ToString` *is* a Function. It cannot be anything else.

Comment: Note that the VB compiler is more intelligent than the C# one and knows that you don't need to add `()` on the end of everything.

Comment: I did try this just to make sure and it yielded the same results.

Comment: Sorry i was using C# code. In VB its not evaluating script in head section. If you use that in body part its working properly. So you might need to add a server side control and change href on page load.

Comment: It *is* working in the head section if a blank string is prepended. The question is why it doesn't work without it.

Comment: Remove the quotation marks on the script use it as `href=<% Response.Write(Request.Url.ToString) %>`. Sometimes ASP.NET understands the control as `HtmlLink` control and displays `href` as literal text.